# What is the .lclass extension

Tags: java, class, decompiler

I was decompiling a jar file to see if i could look at the source code, however, I saw that instead of .class files in the .jar file, there were .lclass files. I did some googling and came up with nothing, the only slight thing I could gather is that it means "local class" but I dont think that is the case as ALL of the classes in the jar file are .lclass. This was meant for Java 8.

Comment: It appears something to do with the Lunar client for Minecraft.  If this is the case, then diassembling their code is likely to be a violation of the Lunar client [Terms of Service](https://www.lunarclient.com/terms/) (section 3.3) and you would be advised to stop.  (And >we< would be advised to not assist you!!)

Answer (score 1):

Rename it to .class file :D (.lclass -> .class) and then decompile!